# How to redirect URL with Equal "=" sign , Number , Question mark to another URL in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

How to define redirect rule to convert URL in `.htaccess` file.

**Example :-**

```
"/component/jsn/code003?tmpl=component&Itemid=101"
```

convert to

```
"/hdsurprises"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)